# how to make this function count backwards

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

There is this `getNextPlayer()` function that counts forwards, but I want to adapt it for a card game that occasionally requires counting backwards.

```
def GetNextPlayer(self, p):
    """ Return the player to the left of the specified player, skipping players who have been knocked out
    """
    next = (p % self.numberOfPlayers) + 1
    # Skip any knocked-out players
    while next != p and self.knockedOut[next]:
        next = (next % self.numberOfPlayers) + 1
    return next
```

Its from a gard game script found at http://www.aifactory.co.uk/newsletter/ISMCTS.txt and is part of a larger monte carlo tree search algorithm. I tried `next=(p%self.numberOfPlayers)-1` but it produces invalid values

Comment: what does "occasionally" mean here?

Comment: Is it possible to reverse the input instead?

Comment: @PPG There is a local game called Matatu only played in uganda and if a Jack is played, the direction of play is reversed.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you have tried and "produces invalid values"?

Comment: @MutationalMeltdown p is the current player, I dont know if providing the last player won't just give the current player, hence a No operation

Comment: I think you need to apply modulo after the -1

Comment: At first I though p was the position of the player (2 if he is playing second) but `(p % self.numberOfPlayers)` make me doubt it. What is `p` ? If p is the position : `p<=numberOfPlayers` --> `p % numberOfPlayers = p (or 0 if p = numberOfPlayers) ` isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the `+1` to `-1` produces invalid values because the `modulo` operator ignores the sign in the case where you would do `0 - 1 % self.numberOfPlayers`. E.g. `-1 % 4 == 3`

**Update, thanks to @pwnsauce**, this should produce what you need:

`p - 1 if p >= 1 else self.numberOfPlayers - 1`

This assumes that player indices start at `0` and go to `self.numberOfPlayers-1`

Comment: I'm not convinced of the modulo necessity. wouldn't a :
`p - 1 if p >= 1 else self.numberOfPlayers - 1 ` be the same ?

Comment: @pwnsauce that's true. And it's much cleaner. I will update the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It wasn't necessary in the `GetNextPlayer()` either btw.

Comment: @pwnsauce that's true, although it is quite concise in the original `GetNextPlayer()`. For me, I always have the notion of 'wraps around' when I see `%` operators.

Comment: yup it's concise. I think the player indice start at 1 tho. because  `next = (p % self.numberOfPlayers) + 1` return something between/equal 1 and self.numberOfPlayers

Comment: Or it is a bug. In any case, if there is no strong reason for it to start at 1, I think it's an anti-pattern and should be fixed. Next thing you know is that you have a collection of player numbers and it's all gone haywire with `if`s, `±1`s etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
def GetNextPlayer(self, p, forward=True):
    """ Return the player to the left of the specified player, skipping players who have been knocked out
    """
    def get_next():
        ref = p if forward else p + self.numberOfPlayers - 1
        return p + 1

    next = get_next()
    # Skip any knocked-out players
    while next != p and self.knockedOut[next]:
        next = get_next()
    return next
```

I have separated the reference (count starting from 0) and periodic property (modulo operation). And also made it generic for both backward and forward

Comment: This produces an error as it is written there, because `get_next()` doesn't take any arguments, yet you pass one when calling it here: `get_next(forward)`

Comment: Sorry. Corrected. Initially i had placed the forward argument inside the inner function. Later forget to remove it. Does it work?

Comment: I am not the OP but, with all due respect, if you post complete code, like the method you wrote, you should be reasonably sure that it will actually work. I commented on it because I was sure it wouldn't work.